# Is there a way to check if one table has all the records from an answer table for one specific id in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare two tables: a table that has results, and a table that has the answer/key. I want the result table to have records that match exactly what the answer table has for a specific column id. This result table has:

I am using SQL Server 2008 and this is my query:

```
select id 
from Answer 
left outer join Result on Answer.mappingId = Result.mappingId
                       and Answer.answerValue = Result.answerValue
left outer join Check on Result.checkId = Check.checkId
```

Here are the tables I am using:

**Result** table -- checkId = 100 is what I want in this example

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 1 | 15          | 100      |  1
 2 | 16          | 100      |  1
 3 | 17          | 100      |  1
 4 | 18          | 100      |  1
 5 | 15          | 200      |  1
 6 | 16          | 200      |  1
 7 | 17          | 200      |  2
 8 | 18          | 200      |  2
```

**Answer** table:

```
id | mappingId   | answerValue
---+-------------+------------
 1 | 15          | 1          
 2 | 16          | 1            
 3 | 17          | 1            
 4 | 18          | 1
```

The result table, notice that there are the same id's for checkId (4 of id 100 and 4 of id 200). I want to be able to know if the answer value is 1 for all of one specific checkId. So the result table for checkId= 100 is what I want the query to find the existence of, since it has all of the correct answers for that single id value (4 records for that checkId = 100, which is what I want because the answer table has 4 answers. The mapping Id's also need to match, which they do: 15, 16, 17, 18). But for 200, it doesn't have all of the answers. It only has the correct answer for mapping id 15, 16.

Example of result table which is not what I want but still appears to pass my query

Result table - still passes even though it's not supposed to

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 1 | 15          | 100      |  1
 2 | 16          | 100      |  1
 3 | 17          | 100      |  2
 4 | 18          | 100      |  2
 5 | 15          | 200      |  2
 6 | 16          | 200      |  2
 7 | 17          | 200      |  1
 8 | 18          | 200      |  1
```

This should be incorrect, since only two of the questions have the correct answer value of 1--for mappingId 15/16 for checkId = 100. But the issue is that since checkId = 200 has the remaining correct values-- for mappingId 17/18, my query still regards this as correct, even though I want mappingId: 15, 16, 17, 18 with answer values of 1 for all for one specific checkId= 100. Note: it just has to be for any one specific checkId so the below is still fine and what I would like:

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 1 | 15          | 100      |  2
 2 | 16          | 100      |  2
 3 | 17          | 100      |  2
 4 | 18          | 100      |  2
 5 | 15          | 200      |  1
 6 | 16          | 200      |  1
 7 | 17          | 200      |  1
 8 | 18          | 200      |  1
```

Because checkId 200 has mappingId: 15, 16, 17, 18 with all answerValues as 1's.

This is what I want to return

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 5 | 15          | 200      |  1
 6 | 16          | 200      |  1
 7 | 17          | 200      |  1
 8 | 18          | 200      |  1
```

OR:

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 1 | 15          | 100      |  1
 2 | 16          | 100      |  1
 3 | 17          | 100      |  1
 4 | 18          | 100      |  1
```

If the either of the above aren't true, it would return nothing at all. It has to have all the correct answers for one specific checkId. An all or nothing deal, basically.

What I am actually returning and is incorrect since it spans 2 checkId's

```
id | mappingId   | checkId  |  answerValue     
---+-------------+----------+---------------
 1 | 15          | 100      |  1
 2 | 16          | 100      |  1
 3 | 17          | 200      |  1
 4 | 18          | 200      |  1
```

Thanks for the help everyone! I am new to stack overflow, so let me know if there's anything I could have done better. I couldn't figure out how to color the SQL query, so forgive me and I hope it is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One conceptually easy way to handle this is to join the two tables, and then aggregate by `checkId`, asserting that every answer matches:

```
SELECT
    c.checkId
FROM [Check] c
LEFT JOIN Answer a
    ON c.mappingId = a.mappingId AND c.answerValue = a.answerValue
GROUP BY
    c.checkId
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = COUNT(a.mappingId);
```

### Demo

Comment: Works like a charm! Though to add, if I wanted to make it more complex to where all answers must match for a specific checkId, but also another specific id that appears in a different table that I would have to join. How would that change your query to handle that. You can maybe imagine a "checkId2" column perse. Would this require some loop like inside a while? Thanks again.

Comment: You might be able to adapt my answer to these new requirements, though at this point you might want to just open a new question.  Next time you ask, just try to give us a _minimal_ amount of sample data, just enough for us to get the idea of your problem.